# public/index.html tuning in vue-cli

Tags: vue-cli

Is it possible to configure injected files places in `public/index.html`?
I want to generate a django template instead of simple html file provided, it could look like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header_extra %}
    <!-- app.css -->
{% endblock %}

{% block js_extra %}
    <!-- app.js, chunk-vendors.js, etc -->
{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}
    <div id="app"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to do it, first it's required to disable files injecting in `vue.config.js`:

```
configureWebpack: config => {
  config.plugins.forEach((plugin) => {
    if(plugin.constructor.name === 'HtmlWebpackPlugin') {
      plugin.options.inject = false;
      plugin.options.minify.collapseWhitespace = false;
    }
  });
}
```

For the next it's needed to insert js / css files using underscore templating.
Here I'm prepending `vue` before file names, cause I collect static with django.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block header_extra %}
  <% htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css.forEach((fileName) => { %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vue<%= fileName %>' %}">
  <% }) %>
{% endblock %}

{% block js_extra %}
  <% htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js.forEach((fileName) => { %>
    <script src="{% static 'vue<%= fileName %>' %}"></script>
  <% }) %>
{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}
    <div id="app"></div>

    <!--
    <pre id="config">
        <%= JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin, null, 2) %>
    </pre>
    -->
{% endblock %}
```

Then, cause I have to collect static to `static/vue` directory, in settings.py I added a new dir:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # vue is an additional subdirectory for vue static
    ('vue', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/dist')),
]
```

Also it's needed to have an access to the vue generated template from django, so in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    # ...
    # 'frontend' is the vue project directory name,
    # so you should be able to specify template like this:
    # template_name='dist/index.html'

    {'DIRS': ['frontend']}
    # ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

If someone prefers the webpack chain way:

```js
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.values().forEach( p => {
      if (p.get('plugin').name === 'HtmlWebpackPlugin') {
        // console.log(p.get('args'))
        p.tap(args => [ merge(args[0], {
          inject: false,
        })]);
        // console.log(p.get('args'))
      }
    })
  }
```